# Is it correct to say "They quoted us for $20"?

Tags: meaning

Could I say "They quote us for $20 for this project"?

Comment: No. 'The quote they have given us is $20.'

Comment: Yes, if they charged $20 to tell you how much the project would cost.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

for - negotiable price
at - fixed rate

A quote can be negotiable, yes you can say.